# Return day Name in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to return the name of day like `Saturday`  or `Monday`
I used this code :

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.Day);

MessageBox.Show(date.DayOfWeek.ToString());
```

But it doesn't work it return the name of day but doesn't correct day 
and when i change the date in my computer it still return the same day

Comment: Why are you doing `new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.Day)`? What do you expect that to do? `Day` returns a number between 1 and 31, indicating the day of the month. The constructor that accepts a single number is expecting the number of ticks that have occurred since January 01, 0001 at midnight.

Comment: DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now);

Comment: You should read one more documentation of [`DateTime.DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Rather try something like

```
MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString());
```

[DateTime.Today Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.today.aspx)

> Gets the current date.

Your problem is that

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.Day);
```

evaluates to

```
{01/Jan/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

The constructor you used was [DateTime Constructor (Int64)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the DateTime structure to a specified
>   number of ticks.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.Day)
```

Should be:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(DateTime.Now)
```

You are putting the day in a date variable which will probably be in the year 1900.

Comment: `DateTime date = DateTime.Now` will do it.